# Apache POI Workbook class not found

Tags: java, apache-poi

First, I want let you know what I'm using:

- Eclipse IDE 2018-09 (4.9.0) Java-SE 10
- Apache POI 4.0.0-20180907

I don't mixing any JARs files with other version and I add to my project all the JARs in the folder except "poi-examples-4.0.0".

Let take a look of this code:

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    }
}
```

I getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook
>       at Program.main(Program.java:8)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>       ... 1 more

And if I'm trying this code:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    }
}
```

I getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook
>       at Program.main(Program.java:8)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>       ... 1 more

Can someone can explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maven dependency to use: `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.0</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` is a run time error. So while compile time the class `HSSFWorkbook` was found. But on run time the same class was not found. So there must be a discrepancy between class path settings compile time vs. run time. Check your IDE settings for that. But for using `XSSFWorkbook` please read: [Can Apache POI be compiled/used with Java 10 or newer?](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-java10).

Comment: @AxelRichter thank you very much, do you have any suggestion for alternative project that support java 10?

Comment: Apache POI does support Java 10, just not with modules, see the FAQ which Axel linked to!